# Android MediaPlayer Sound res Problem

Tags: android, media-player

I have 40+ sound files in my application. In one of my activities I want to play `only one sound file` base on the `id` that come with the `Bundle b` (id range: 1 - 50). I tried this:

**In onCreate():**

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    id = (int) b.getInt("id");
    tv.setText("id : "+id); // Just to make sure that I received a correct id
    setResourseId(id);
    mPlayer.start();
```

**the setResourceId():**

```
public void setResourseId(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 1:     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
    case 2:     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
    case 3:     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
    case 4:     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);
    case 5:     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound5);
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
    default:    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound0);
    }
}
```

**However,** it always play the `sound0 file` (the default one) ! It seems strange, since the `TextView tv` **always** prints the correct *id*

-

Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [switch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), you need to break after each case, otherwise the next lines will be executed as well, in your case, all lines were executed each time and the last assignment to mPlayer was `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);` each time. A short fix - add break after each case:

```
switch(id) {
    case 1:
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        break;
    ....
}
```

As a side note - I would consider using an array of ids and avoiding this long switch case.

Comment: I forgot to add it, since I was initially returning a MediaPlayer object. Thanks.